# rxjs - what is the difference from result perspective to do actions in .do() and .subscribe()

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

For examples, I have the following code that I can write in two ways:

```
1. 
ObsevableA.do(() => { 
   doSomething();
})
.subscribe();

2.
ObservableA.subscribe(() => {
  doSomething();
});
```

The end result seems to be the same. Any thoughts on each approach? What is the best practice I should be using? Thanks.

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-move-important-side-effects-from-do-to-subscribe

My initial thought is similar to what it says here. if doSomething() method does some business logic that would affect the application flow,  I should use 2. approach?

.do() is mainly for performing side effect operations such as logging. But I am interested in what other people is using .do()

Comment: subscribe has next, error and complete functions,. I use do only in the middle to troubleshoot and perform some side effect like showing spinner..Plus 1.) is longer to write ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd summarize it into a few points:

1. The Observable chain doesn't emit anything until you call `subscribe()`.
2. You can call `subscribe()` with no parameters while `do()` always needs to have at least one parameter (because there's no point in using `do()` without any handler).
3. If your chain sends an error and you don't setup any error handler in you `subscribe()` call the error will be rethrow. This doesn't apply to `.do()` because it just passes everything through without any further logic.

In general it's recommended to use `do()` only to perform side-effects and to debug your Observable chains. The good thing with `do()` is that you can place it anywhere you want but you should avoid using it to modify the chain values further.

For example you shouldn't do something like this:

```
let sum = 0;

Observable.range(1, 3)
    .do(val => sum += val)
    .concat(Observable.of({ total: sum}))
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

This prints:

```
1
2
3
{total: 6}
```

When you can write it in more Rx way:

```
Observable.range(1, 3)
    .publish(shared => Observable
        .merge(shared, shared.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0).map(sum => { return { total: sum }; }))
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I do not think you need to pass any param into .do(). Do operator does map() that return the input value behind the scene.

Comment: @schrodinger'scode You do have to pass at least one argument to `do()`. You can check it for yourself here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/do.ts#L8. Also it's not using `map()` internally because `map()` wraps the callback call in a try-catch block and eventually propagates the exception as an error signal. You obviously don't want to do with `do()` which is only supposed to call side-effects and not to modify the chain at all.

Comment: no, suppose anyone can doSomething() which do not modify the chain at all but it does not mean you should use do operator to do so?

Answer (score 0):

`do()` returns an output observable and doesn't consume values from the source observable. You can use it for side effects in the reactive chain.

`subscribe()` returns a subscription and does consume values from the source observable. You use it at the end of the reactive chain to process the result of your computation. The returned subscription object has a `dispose()` method you can call to unsubscribe all the observables.